# When to use styled component vs when to use css prop in emotion?

Tags: emotion

Is there a best practice or list of pros and cons in deciding when to use a styled component instead of the css prop?

Answer (score 2):

I generally prefer `styledComponent` but, there are certain edge cases like styling your `<Link />` for react-router where you have to provide a compiled style to className prop.

There is no harm in using CSS props but, there is a chance of accidentally overriding your styles, plus it makes your JSX messier. But if you know what you are doing and you are heavily using [composition](https://emotion.sh/docs/composition) then IMO it is quite a powerful feature.

It is much easier to understand and manage the styled-components, like when using themes you can encapsulate the whole styling logic away from your JSX. +1 to styled-components for lego based design.

I think it is safe to say, you can use styled-components and CSS together but adopting either one for the majority of your components.

I absolutely love how you can override your base components using emotion's composition(which saves us from passing weird props and helps to keep the props cleaner) but at the same time you should not abuse it as from personal experience it's tempting to just use CSS composition where you should be using props like `isBold` `fontSize: "sm"` ...